# How to implement server side rendering in Laravel and Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I want to implement server side rendering in Laravel and Vuejs , Actually I want to render Vue Component.

I understand that I have to use V8js but V8js installation on Windows is almost impossible.
I've seen a few cases in stackoverflow but no one helped me .

My questions :

1. How to install v8js in Windows (Xampp or Wampserver) ??
2. Is there any other way to implement server side rendering (Laravel + Vuejs)?

Comment: `Laravel` itself is `server side`

Comment: I want render vue component .

Comment: No(almost) you need v8js to execute js codes. But you can switch your os to Linux or run it on server, I don't think shared hosts have this v8js extension